# Сравнение данных их двух таблиц и занесение данных в третью

Tags: mysql

Доброй ночи! Проблема такая. Есть две таблицы в БД - в одной "ответы студента на тест", в другой "ключи к тесту". Требуется написать процедуру или функцию, которая бы сравнивала соответствующие значения (ответ на №1 и ключ к №1), и заносила в третью таблицу (результаты) значение 1 если ответ совпал с ключом, и 0 если не совпал.

Вот коды таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_keys`
(   `variant` int(5) NOT NULL,  
 `ex_1` varchar(3) NOT NULL,   `ex_2`
 varchar(3) NOT NULL,   `ex_3`
 varchar(3) NOT NULL,   `ex_4`
 varchar(5) NOT NULL,   `ex_5`
 varchar(5) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
 (`variant`),   UNIQUE KEY `variant`
 (`variant`),   UNIQUE KEY `variant_2`
 (`variant`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
 CHARSET=utf8;
 --
 -- Дамп данных таблицы `test_keys`
 --
 INSERT INTO `test_keys` (`variant`,
 `ex_1`, `ex_2`, `ex_3`, `ex_4`,
 `ex_5`) VALUES (11, 'B', 'B', 'A',
 'B', 'B'), (13, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A',
 'A'), (51, 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C');
 //-----------------------
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
 `test_papers` (   `student_id` int(10)
 NOT NULL,   `test_id` int(10) NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCREMENT,   `variant` int(5) NOT
 NULL,   `ex_1` varchar(3) NOT NULL,  
 `ex_2` varchar(3) NOT NULL,   `ex_3`
 varchar(3) NOT NULL,   `ex_4`
 varchar(5) NOT NULL,   `ex_5`
 varchar(5) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
 (`test_id`),   KEY `student_id`
 (`student_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8
 ;
 --
 -- Дамп данных таблицы `test_papers`
 INSERT INTO `test_papers`
 (`student_id`, `test_id`, `variant`,
 `ex_1`, `ex_2`, `ex_3`, `ex_4`,
 `ex_5`) VALUES (14, 6, 13, 'A', 'B',
 'B', 'B', 'C'), (1, 7, 51, 'C', 'C',
 'B', 'A', 'C');
//-----------------
-- Структура таблицы `test_results`
--
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
 `test_results` (   `stud_id` int(10)
 NOT NULL,   `test_id` int(10) NOT
 NULL,   `variant` int(5) NOT NULL,  
 `ex_1` int(2) NOT NULL,   `ex_2`
 int(2) NOT NULL,   `ex_3` int(2) NOT
 NULL,   `ex_4` int(2) NOT NULL,  
 `ex_5` int(2) NOT NULL,   `mark`
 int(2) NOT NULL,   KEY `stud_id`
 (`stud_id`),   KEY `test_id`
 (`test_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
 CHARSET=utf8;
 --
 -- Дамп данных таблицы `test_results`
 --
 INSERT INTO `test_results` (`stud_id`,
 `test_id`, `variant`, `ex_1`, `ex_2`,
 `ex_3`, `ex_4`, `ex_5`, `mark`) VALUES
 (13, 1, 44, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3), (14, 6,
 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0), (16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вам вставлять в таблицу? просто запросом нельзя обойтись?

```
SELECT tp.student_id, tp.test_id, tp.variant,
  if(tp.ex_1 = tk.ex_1,1,0) ex_1,
  if(tp.ex_2 = tk.ex_2,1,0) ex_2,
  if(tp.ex_3 = tk.ex_3,1,0) ex_3,
  if(tp.ex_4 = tk.ex_4,1,0) ex_4,
  if(tp.ex_5 = tk.ex_5,1,0) ex_5,
  if(tp.ex_1 = tk.ex_1,1,0)+
  if(tp.ex_2 = tk.ex_2,1,0)+
  if(tp.ex_3 = tk.ex_3,1,0)+
  if(tp.ex_4 = tk.ex_4,1,0)+
  if(tp.ex_5 = tk.ex_5,1,0) AS mark
FROM test_papers tp
  JOIN test_keys tk ON tp.variant = tk.variant;
```